# Customlistview changed button when we are added database in android?

Tags: android

Hi i am created customlistview added one button first time i am insert value in 0.When i have to click that add button value is 1 changed in database.Getting column value result.

Note**Getting value result 1 means changed button or color.I am used in baseadapter**

here i have mention sample code also:

```
            holder.btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("product", arrListproduct_name
                            .get(position).toString().trim());
                    hashMap.put(
                            "price",
                            getDoublePrecision(arrListproductprice
                                    .get(position).toString().trim()));
                    hashMap.put("productID", arrlistproduct_id
                            .get(position).toString().trim());
                    hashMap.put("quantity", datavalue);
                    hashMap.put("resturantID",
                            category.dinein_restaurant_id);
                    hashMap.put("value", Str_value);
                    arrListproductdatabase.add(hashMap);
                    if (dataBase.ProductExist(
                            DatabaseHelper.TABLErestaurant,
                            arrlistproduct_id.get(position).toString()
                                    .trim())) {
                        Toast.makeText(VegNonVegClass.this,
                                "Update successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        for (int i = 0; i < GetAllitemDetailsItem.size(); i++) {
                            dataBase.updateData1(
                                    GetAllitemDetailsItem.get(i).get("id"),
                                    DatabaseHelper.TABLErestaurant, "1");
                        }

                    } else {
                        dataBase.insertData(DatabaseHelper.TABLErestaurant,
                                arrListproductdatabase);
                        arrListproductdatabase.clear();
                        Toast.makeText(VegNonVegClass.this,
                                "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        // arrListproductdatabase.remove(position);
                        // notifyDataSetChanged();
                        ArrayList<String> selectedno = dataBase
                                .getselectedTrue();
                        for (String s : selectedno) {
                            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                holder.btn_add
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkout);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.totalAmount(String.valueOf(Str_subtotal));
                    }

                }

            });
```

Issues **Button is changed but listview refresh means automatically changed previous button** Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue, but I believe you're saying that the value of the button is changing, but its view in the list is not changing appropriately, correct?

If so, that's because of how the list view's adapter works. It's designed to be efficient by re-using inflated views that are already created, instead of recreating them every time.

First, try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

If that doesn't update your problem, it's probably because you're not actually changing the data in the adapter; just the value it represents.

Make sure you're overriding the adapter's getView() method appropriately as well:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if(row == null)
    {
        row = (((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater()).inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);            
    }

    try{
        // Set what the view should show here

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return row;
}
```